# Modify data in column without creating a new column

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a column with time values in milliseconds from a query and I want to convert those values to hours in the same column. The essence is that I don't want to create a new column to do so.

I've tried tinkering with Table.ReplaceValue but I've not been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using standard mathematical Divide function in Power Query -> Transform -> Standard -> Divide

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

The second procedure is to write M code inside Power Query to perform the operation. One benefit of this approach is that it allows the use of conditional expressions such as "if" and "elseif", which may not be available through the common GUI operations.Image attached below with code snippest you can use to achieve current goal.

Thanks     [PowerQuery Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Taw6R.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).